# How to update ONLY the PHP version without updating xamp on localhost

Tags: php, xampp

I tried to download the latest PHP version ( trying to update PHP from 7.0.* to 7.2.* ) and replace the PHP folder at xamp and restart it. Got following error.

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
7:14:41 AM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
7:14:41 AM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
7:14:41 AM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
7:14:41 AM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
7:14:41 AM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
7:14:41 AM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

How can I update PHP version only without updating XAMP ? Is it possible ?

Comment: Why would you do that? Just copy your htdocs folder and your php.ini (if you changed it) and download the newest xampp.

Comment: on which port and operating system your xampp is running?